# MacBook Pro built-in keyboard and trackpad not working, PRAM reset needed

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, high-sierra, trackpad

The keyboard and trackpad of my MacBook Pro 2015 suddenly stopped working. I searched the Internet and did a SMC and PRAM reset with an external keyboard.

The PRAM reset (I reset the PRAM with command+option+P+R as explained [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)) helped solve the issue: I could use the keyboard and tracked again, so I think it is not a hardware issue, but after a restart it stopped working again.

I tried **Apple Diagnostics** (as explained [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)) and it returns `No issues found. Reference Code: ADP000`. So I confirmed it is not hardware issue.

I also tried **reinstalling** macOS, but it didn't help, the problem persists.
This reinstallation kept all my previous data and settings

**Do I need to reset the PRAM every time I start my Mac? What is the problem with my MacBook? How do I permanently reset the PRAM? And what about Wipe all data and reinstall macOS, will it solve this problem?**

Comment: OS X has an onboard diagnostic suite which you can run by pressing the `D` key on startup. Here's [a link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) to an Apple Support page on that. Run the tool and see what comes up.

Comment: @marshki It returns `No issues found. Reference Code: ADP000`

Comment: I saw a thread that indicates this is a know problem with this model. The likely fault is with the Mac's trackpad cable, which would need to be replaced. Here's the [thread](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/335907/Internal+keyboard+and+trackpad+not+working). If there's an Apple store nearby, have them take a look.